# Writing a test for CodeMirror

Tags: codemirror

I would like to write a simple test for CodeMirror

```
test(' codemirror ', () => {

    let text = document.createElement("div");

    let settings = {}

    codemirror(text, { ...settings, value: '' });
});
```

However when I run this I get :

> TypeError: document.body.createTextRange is not a function
>
> ```
> at range (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:94:25)
> at hasBadBidiRects (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:1343:12)
> at buildLineContent (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:1838:9)
> at updateExternalMeasurement (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:2442:28)
> at prepareMeasureForLine (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:2478:14)
> at measureChar (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:2451:34)
> at endOperation_R2 (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:3766:24)
> at endOperations (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:3732:7)
> at A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:3719:5
> at finishOperation (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:2132:5)
> at endOperation (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:3716:3)
> at new CodeMirror$1 (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:7448:3)
> at CodeMirror$1 (A:\frontend\node_modules\codemirror\lib\codemirror.js:7389:49)
> ```

What am I doing wrong here?

My import looks like this :

```
import codemirror from 'codemirror';
```

And I am using : "codemirror": "5.25.0",

Answer (score 2):

I managed to stub out some functions and now it works. It is not a very nice solution though :(

```
test(' codemirror test ', () => {

    let div = document.createElement("div");

    document.body.createTextRange = (elem) => {
        let textRange = {
            getBoundingClientRect: ()=>1,
            getClientRects: ()=>1
        }
        return textRange;
    }

    codemirror(div);
});
```